# Which of these is correct: "Sheila is now in Facebook" or "Sheila is now on Facebook"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, in-on, social-media

Can I also use *in* when referring to someone who is already a member of Facebook?

Comment: Related: [“in the internet” and “on the internet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/in-the-internet-and-on-the-internet), [“on website” or “at website”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8226/on-website-or-at-website), [to add someone “to” Facebook or “on” Facebook](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9769/to-add-someone-to-facebook-or-on-facebook)

Comment: possible duplicate of [This question has been asked at/on SO?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-on-so)

Answer (score 14):

It's my opinion that you get on Facebook. Not in it.

Just as you are online and offline.

> Sheila is online
>
> Sheila is on Facebook.

However, if Sheila recently became a big fan of Facebook..

> Shelia is now into Facebook.

Comment: To expand on this, most websites work the same way: "I posted a video on YouTube." "Did you read the article on that blog?"

Answer (score 5):

I think:

> Shelia is now in Facebook.

would, possibly, imply that Shelia has joined Facebook as an employee. Whereas

> Shelia is now on Facebook.

would imply that Shelia, now, has a profile on Facebook.

Comment: "Shelia is now at Facebook" would probably be more common for an employment change.

Comment: I did consider 'at' but in this part of the world, we generally use 'at' to refer to temporary location. Eg: He is at Walmart. Meaning the person is at Walmart to buy something rather than being employed with them. For employment purposes, we use either 'in' as above or even 'with' - Shelia is now with Facebook.

Comment: Of course, I have come across 'at' being used to convey employment relationship and seems fairly valid. I would say, it is a case regional conventions.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine on Facebook comes from the usage of "on TV". The **on** being from "on the stage".

Interesting that you are **on** tv or **on** the radio but ***in** a play

Answer (score 1):

The answer may depend on the first language. The way you think of the situation.
Prepositions are always subjective.
Firstly know the connection between subject and landmark
Here the subject is Sheila and landmark is facebook.

Sheila is using the facebook, not an integral part of facebook(meaning wheather Sheila is there or not **on** facebook, facebook will continue to work).

If Sheila is **in** facebook, then she is integral part of facebook. Here she is using facebook.Therefore, the correct form will be

> Sheila is on facebook.

Take for example.

> Cat is on the table.....(1)

But why not

> Table is under the cat...(2)

Sentence (1) is correct because, we consider huger/heavier objects to be not moveable 
quite as easily as the smaller objects; and hence with respect to heavier object, we
form the connection.

If sentence (2) were to be correct then use can say for the example like this

> Facebook is **with** Sheila......(3)

or

> Facebook is **under** Sheila......(4)

Both (3) and (4) are not correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Facebook strongly requests that the only acceptable language for indicating that your business or organization page is active on their site is "Find us on Facebook". (This is to avoid the trademark dilution potential of phrases such as "Check out our Facebook page".) There is language inertia from "online" as well.

Answer (score 0):

"Sheila is now in Facebook" would imply that she's *inside* Facebook, which could possibly mean she was inside their headquarters.  ([Example of this usage type](https://twitter.com/jephjacques/status/66593134460669952)).  It would make no sense to be inside an abstract/digital concept like a website.

Likewise, it makes no sense to be on top of a website.  But what you're really saying is "Sheila is *shown on* Facebook".  Formerly, websites were static, and featured content **on** them.  We've simply extended the usage for dynamic websites that you can join.  "Is on" now means "has joined" or "is a member of" when used this way.