# Is it “on Facebook“ or “in Facebook“?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, internet, social-media

For preposition of places, should Facebook, an Internet space, be used as *in* or *on*? E.g.

> Find us in Facebook.

Comment: Web pages are like helipads - we navigate to them and land _on_ them.

Comment: Related: [“In the Internet” vs. “on the Internet”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4419/in-the-internet-and-on-the-internet), [“This question has been asked at StackOverflow” vs. “on StackOverflow”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3491/this-question-has-been-asked-at-on-so), [To add someone “to” Facebook or “on” Facebook](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9769/to-add-someone-to-facebook-or-on-facebook)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I usually hear "Find us *on* Facebook." It's the shortened version of "Find us on the Internet site called Facebook". And since site (whether Internet or not) is used with *on*, Facebook also is used with *on*. The same goes for the page (also does not matter, Internet page or a book page) by the way.